# how can I run an JavaScript function once a <script> appear

Tags: javascript, html

hey so I have a problem with my HTML script
so first I had this

index.html

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="loadplayer.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
const script = document.createElement("div")
script.innerHTML = urlvid
const player = document.getElementById("head")
player.appendChild(script)
```

in the script, there is a function named loadvideoplayer()

loadplayer.js

```
function loadvideoplayer(title){
    let array = {title}
    console.log(array)
    console.log(array.title.sources[0].file)
    
    console.log("Loaded")
}
```

the problem is the function on the script tag from index.js is not executed after the  is created
how can i make it executed after the  created ?

btw the urlvid contain this

```
loadvideoplayer(
    {
    title : '',
    tracks: [{
        file: '',
        kind: 'captions',
        'default': true
    }],
    sources: [{'file':'vidurl','type':'video/mp4'}],
    image: "imgurl",
    captions:
        {
        color:'#FFFF00',fontSize:17,backgroundOpacity:50
    },
}
);
```

Comment: you have to execute the script inside a window.onload() listner, so it will only render your changes once the window is loaded

Comment: so in my case is

Comment: script.onload() ??

Comment: Are you trying to create a script inside the `<head>`? In that case you should convert your `div` into a `script`

Comment: at least you should run the function by calling `loadvideoplayer("test_title")` after the function definition it wont run when not called like that

Comment: I have a problem
the loadvideoplayer(things) needs 'things' to run
and the things are from the 'script' tag

Comment: What does `urlvid` contain?

Comment: a script tag from another website that i scrap with cheerio

Comment: You can place your script inline, after the selected element or run the script when the page have loaded. You can read more here about running scripts as soon as the DOM has loaded: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move your HTML declaration like this:

```html
<!-- import libraries before executing code -->
<script src="loadplayer.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```js
function loadVideoPlayer(title) {
  console.log('Loaded Video: ', title);
}

let script = document.createElement('script');

script.innerHTML = 'console.log("Appended script executed!"); myObject = { title: "Wonderful Stack Overflow Answers" };'

document.head.appendChild(script);
loadVideoPlayer(myObject.title)
```

Obviously you must know in advance what are the variables in the script you are injecting into your page (like `myObject` in the example). Without knowing the script you are loading you can't use its variables.

Note that as we are using `innerHTML` and not `src` in the appended script, you can just trigger the function just after appended the child into the document head.
If you use `src`, the browser will ask asynchronously the script, so you must do:

I also warn you on the fact that injecting a script into a page is **always** a security risk, so you **must** rely on what you are injecting (it is a secure source?).

```js
script.addEventListener('load', function() {
  loadVideoPlayer(myObject.title)
});
```

*Side Note:* you could also use [`eval` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), many will state that **eval is evil**, but you are actually ignoring the same security risks by evaluating the code in the script tag:

```js
function loadVideoPlayer(title) {
  console.log('Loaded Video: ', title);
}

let script = 'console.log("Appended script executed!"); myObject = { title: "Wonderful Stack Overflow Answers" };'

eval(script);
loadVideoPlayer(myObject.title)
```